# Google OAuth 2.0 failing with Error 400: invalid_request for some client_id, Can't Sign in because 'App' sent an invalid request

Tags: flutter, firebase, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, invalid-request-uri

I have an Flutter app that uses [googleapis_auth 1.3.1](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis_auth) and [googleapis 9.2.0](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis) .
What I have done:

- enabled the Google Calender API
- connect Flutter Project to Firebase
  and set up with basic template.

But I am getting the following error:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
`
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:googleapis/calendar/v3.dart' as cal;
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'gCalender/calendar_client.dart';
import 'secert.dart';
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart';

void main() async {
  //firebase initialize
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  //google apis init
  var clientID =  ClientId(Secret.getId(),"");
  var scopes = [cal.CalendarApi.calendarEventsScope];
  await clientViaUserConsent(clientID, scopes, prompt).then((AuthClient client) async {
    CalendarClient.calendar = cal.CalendarApi(client);
  });

  
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
void prompt(String url) async {
    if (!await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url))) {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Social Login',
      theme: theme(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialRoute: SplashScreen.routeName,
      // home: const SplashScreen(),
      routes: routes,
    );
  }
}
`
```

I explored the internet but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Any luck finding a solution?

Comment: Yes. I followed the guide here https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/google-apis

Answer (score 1):

if you use emulator, try the app in real phone, cuz some times firebase services not working well in the virtual phones

Comment: Same problem with real devices